# Transfer Windows Server partition to Macbook Air...?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, macbook-air

Basically the problem is. I currently have a HP Elitebook 8530p running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1 and dual boot with Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 SP1 to run 4 virtual machines with Hyper-V.
I'm going to buy a Macbook Air 13" 1.8Ghz/256GB SSD this week or the next week. Now my question is: is there a possible workaround to get the Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 SP1 installation on the Macbook Air? I know you can install Windows on a Mac with their own program, but I don't have the possibility to install all the virtual machines again. They must be copied (or something else).
I was thinking about installing a fresh copy of Server 2008 R2 on the Air and then transfer the virtual machines from the HP to the Air...?

And my last question, does the Air have support for Hyper-V (vt-x, vt-d, or what are the flags called in the CPU)? The CPU does support it, but don't know if the Air itself has it enabled or even knows the technology...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 like you normally would on an Apple computer.  At this point just transfer the virual machine files to the new Windows Server 2008 installation.  As to your second question, you can do your own research on what CPU comes with the AIR, and what Hyper-V extensions it supports.

All of that is documented.

Comment: Oké, first part I already had in my mind. Good to see it is not wrong. Concerning the second question, I know wich CPU is used (Intel® Core™ i7-2677M) and I know it has the proper technology 'flags': VT-x and VT-d but that doesn't mean anything. I saw a lot of laptops having a good CPU with support for VT-x and VT-d but there was no option to turn it on in the BIOS. And in this particular part it's hard for me to search for because this will be my first Mac and don't even know if these guys have a thing called BIOS and so on...

Comment: Got the laptop and can inform you that Server 2008 R2 is running well with Hyper-V enabled and running 4 virtual machines. Dualbooting now is OS X Lion and Server 2008 R2. Works perfectly!

Comment: @BETA911 - I will again point out.  All of the supported features of the CPU you wanted to use is listed on Intel's website.  If it supports those extensions then they are likely enabled by default and cannot be disabled.

Comment: That is wrong Ramhound. Some guys at my school with all sort of other brands of laptops have CPU's from Intel wich support all the VT technologies but still they could not use them simply because they were disabled from the manufacturer side. Modding the BIOS or buy a other laptop were the only solutions. What I'm trying to say is, even if the CPU supports the technologies, if they are internally disabled you can't use them.